# how to modify driver value using python? in compositor

Tags: python, scripting, compositing-nodes, lighting, mathematics

I want to change sunbeam position according to calculated camera transform, sun location. Because my scene is animated, I want to make sunbeam position to according to that information.

In driver, I noticed that's impossible. because there's no driver function like vector calculation; So, I decided to calculate inside of Python.

But I'm not familiar with scripting, I don't know how to connect with drivers and calculate those information.

Comment: Hi. This question was put on hold because as it stands it is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.